# check if currency has valid symbol

Tags: java, currency

I have a string that represents a currency value like $200, €200, ¥200.

As per my task, I support the only the dollar, euro, and yen, but not other currency symbols.

I want to get the first character of string and check if that is a valid currency symbol, which means is that is either Euro or Dollar or Yen but not other currencies. How can do this in Java?

This is my sample code:

```
char c = s.charAt(0);

if(c == dollar || c == euro || c == yen) { // how can I write the symbols in my code?
   valid = true;
} else {
   valid = false;
}
```

Comment: Did you try just writing... The symbols? `'$', '€', '¥'`.

Comment: you can use unicode of currency symbol or key  value pair with currency symbol

Comment: @AndyTurner, I don't want to use special characters like yen or euro in my code

Comment: @abhinavxeon, can you please tell how to do with unicode?

Comment: @learner why not? That's what you're trying to match.

Comment: @learner just copy-paste them in your code.

Comment: You just use `\u`.  So in your case, `$` would be `\u0024`, `€` would be `\u20AC`, and `¥` would be `\u00A5`.  The java lexer will convert them to their unicode equivalents before you get any further, so this will produce the exact same class file.  The only difference will be in your source file.

Comment: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Sc unicode list of currency

Comment: char c1 = '\u0024';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier than you might think:

```
if(c == '$' || c == '€' || c == '¥')
```

You say you don't want to use "special symbols" in your code... I don't understand why you wouldn't; but you can write the euro and Yen symbols as `'\u20AC'` and `'\u00A5'` respectively if you want (but note that the first thing the Java compiler does is to convert them back to `€` and `¥`....)

A strong reason to use the unicode symbol rather than `\uNNNN` is readability: it would be easy to accidentally get the code wrong, and it wouldn't be easy to spot. And, presumably, you're going to write tests for the code - what do you use in the tests to make sure it's doing the right thing? If you use the `\uNNNN` form, you run the risk that you've got it wrong there as well; and if you use the symbol in the tests, then you may as well just use the symbol in the production code as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with unicode

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
 
// Convert list of Characters to string in Java
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  String s="$200";
        char c = s.charAt(0);
        List<Character> currency = Arrays.asList('\u0024', '\u20AC', '\u20AC');
        
        if(currency.contains(c))
        System.out.println("true");
 
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Writing `c == '$' || c == '€' || c == '¥'` is also "doing it with Unicode".   Java chars **are** Unicode.  Java source files are typically UTF-8-encoded Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

How about some pattern matching?
Create separate class for string validation. Pass a `Set` of currency signs you want to match your string against. Compile `pattern` on class initialization (it's heavy operation so better do it once and store the pattern itself). In that case you'll get pattern like this `^[$€¥]\\d+$` (that means - *beginning of the string - any character in square brackets (just one) - one or more digits - end of the string*). Then just pass the `String` to `isValid` method and match against pattern. If you need to change available currencies just add or remove them from `Set` (you can even get them from separate .properties file). This approach makes your app flexible.

```java
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> currencySet = Set.of("$", "€", "¥");
        CurrencyValidator currencyValidator = new CurrencyValidator(currencySet);
        String value = "$200";
        System.out.println(currencyValidator.isValid(value));
    }

}

public class CurrencyValidator {

    private final Set<String> currencySet;
    private Pattern currencyPattern;

    public CurrencyValidator(Set<String> currencySet) {
        this.currencySet = currencySet;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        String currencyString = currencySet.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.joining("", "^[", "]\\d+$"));
        currencyPattern = Pattern.compile(currencyString);
    }

    public boolean isValid(String value) {
        return currencyPattern.matcher(value).matches();
    }
}
```